# Why is the resultant of my improfile function returning with a mirrored graph in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, plot, signal-processing, curve

I am currently running `improfile` on MATLAB with a line going through the center of the picture below:

[image]

After doing so, I'm plotting the resultant using the code below:

```
xi = [1 size(d_Img,2) size(d_Img,2) 1]; 
        yi = [ceil(size(d_Img,1)/2), ceil(size(d_Img,1)/2), ceil(size(d_Img,1)/2 ),ceil(size(d_Img,1)/2)];

    c_d = improfile(d_Img,xi,yi);
    c_c = improfile(c_Img,xi,yi);
    c_d = c_d';
    c_c = c_c';  
    size_c = size(c_d);
    n = 1:size_c(2); 

    plot(n,c_d);
```

And here is the plot:

[image]

Why are the curves mirroring each other? I am asking to gain a better understanding of what exactly `improfile` seems to be achieving in `MATLAB`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`improfile` computes something like a "path integral", it gives you the image intensity values around a user specified path. For example, if you use:

`improfile(img,[1 1],[1 size(img,2)]);`

It gives the same as `img(:,1)`. This is because the path you are using in `improfile` is from `(1,1)` to `(1,size(img,2))` , meaning the first row. However you could definitely add more complicated paths.

In your case you are going trow a path defined by 4 points. The points are, if I substitute your equation by the resultant numbers:

`(1,79)->(134,79)->(134,79)->(1,79)`. Thus, looking at this, it is obvious that your result should be mirrored, because you are integrating over a line the way there, and back!

---

Sidenote:

you can do `plot(c_d);` and forget about that `n`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion too!